# How to turn off specific unwanted validation/hints during project (re)build

Tags: intellij-idea

If I rebuild project, I get bunch of warnings. For example:

```
serializable class Whatever has no definition of serialVersionUID
```

which is complete nonsense(for me), since serialVersionUID is optional and blindly generating one just creates more problems(for me). I want to turn this(and similar) off. I cannot see this anywhere in settings, if I righclick this, I see option to disable this validation, sadly it does nothing and next time I see this again. And all of this happens with suppression of this warning being present in source code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2057")
```

which works for editor, but not for (re)build process.

Comment: Try to adding `<showWarnings>false</showWarnings>` to see it helps
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#showWarnings

Comment: I want all maven warnings, but if I compile it using maven, these are not produced.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect have some compiler warnings enabled in `Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler`. Perhaps there is an `-Xlint` option in `Additional command line parameters`?

To disable all javac warnings use the `Generate no warnings` checkbox that is on that settings page. Or remove the `-Xlint` option, if it is there. Or add `-Xlint:-serial` to the `Additional command line parameters` to only disable the serialization warnings

Comment: no I don't, it's empty. Nothing even in maven-compiler-plugin (bad on my end). but even if I add <arg>-Xlint:all</arg><arg>-Xmaxwarns</arg> to maven I won't get any  serialVersionUID (which is correct, this is valid code, serialiVersionUID is calculated by compiler if missing). But idea still complains...

Comment: It is not IDEA who complains, it is javac.

Comment: might be, but not when it is invoked via maven. How to turn it off then?

Comment: I gave several ways to disable the warning in my answer. Do none of them work for you?

Comment: I want warnings, so generate no warnings cannot be used. I want 'all' warnings, but those questionable ones. Adding `-Xlint:-processing -Xlint:-serial` into additional command line parameters does nothing. `-Xlint:none` does nothing, all warnings still present as before. Option `generate no warnings` removes most warning and only few of them are generated (no does not mean no, evidently). Thanks for helping me, but none of them really works. 'Generate no warnings' was the only way to get rid of annoying ones, but this is not acceptable, as it removes "everything".

Comment: Do you have anything under the `Override compiler settings per-module` setting?